# Assign result of a external function to a variable return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, variables

I am trying to assign the value of an external function to a variable on javascript but it returns undefined

The external function is this, its function is to search for a record in a database

```
function executeGetOneQueryCmd(database, config, query, parameters, res) {
  let connector = new Connector();
  let connection = null;

  connectorLogger.info(
    `Ejecutando una consulta SELECT con clausula WHERE en ${database}`
  );
  switch (database) {
    case databases.DB2:
      connector.setDatabaseController(new NodeJt400Controller());
      connection = connector.startConnection(config);

      connection
        .query(query, parameters)
        .then((results) => {
          return results;
        })
        .fail((error) => {
          connectorLogger.error(error);

          res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
            message: ErrorMessages.QUERY_EXECUTED_WITH_ERRORS,
            error: error,
          });
        });
      break;
    case databases.MYSQL:
      connector.setDatabasesController(new MySQLController());
      connection = connector.startConnection(config);

      try {
        connection.query(query, parameters, (error, results) => {
          if (error) {
            connectorLogger.error(error);

            res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
              message: ErrorMessages.QUERY_EXECUTED_WITH_ERRORS,
              error: error,
            });
          } else {
            return results;
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        connectorLogger.error(error);

        res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
          message: ErrorMessages.AN_ERROR_OCURRED,
          error: error,
        });
      }

      connection.end();

      break;
    default:
      throw ErrorMessages.DATABASE_IS_NOT_DEFINED;
  }
}
```

And the function that assigns the result to the variable is this

with the result of the first function I need to execute another process

```
async function rcxdmRestart(req, res) {
  body = {
    ID: req.body.pos,
  };

  let parameters = utils.parseQueryParametersFromReqBody(body);
  console.log(parameters);
  var result = await connector.executeGetOneQueryCmd(
    dbConfig.type,
    dbConfig.properties,
    queries.getPos,
    parameters,
    res
  );
  console.log("result: ", result);
  // Do something with result
}
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: The `connection.query` promise in `executeGetOneQueryCmd` needs to be returned from the function for it to be `await`ed upon.

Comment: There is an additional complication with the `connection.end()` which I assume you only want to run after the query has completed.

Comment: I already tried this but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all your return statements are inside callbacks so your functions isnt returning anything, also as i can see you are trying to combine promises (async/await) with callbacks i recomend to you stick on promises and do something like this

```
function executeGetOneQueryCmd(database, config, query, parameters, res) {
const connector = new Connector();
let connection = null;

connectorLogger.info(
    `Ejecutando una consulta SELECT con clausula WHERE en ${database}`
);
switch (database) {
    case databases.DB2:
        connector.setDatabaseController(new NodeJt400Controller());
        connection = connector.startConnection(config);
        // if this is a promise you can return it if not you need to create a promise from it
        return connection
            .query(query, parameters)
            // this is not needed
            // .then((results) => {
            //     return results;
            // })
            // i think here you mean catch
            //.fail((error) => {
            .catch((error) => {
                connectorLogger.error(error);

                res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                    message: ErrorMessages.QUERY_EXECUTED_WITH_ERRORS,
                    error: error,
                });
            });
    // not needed because we are returning above
    //break;
    case databases.MYSQL:
        connector.setDatabasesController(new MySQLController());
        connection = connector.startConnection(config);
        //remove try catch and manage in promise mode
        //try {
        // Create a promise from this callback function and return it
        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            // If this code can be a promise it would be better
            connection.query(query, parameters, (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    connectorLogger.error(error);

                    res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                        message: ErrorMessages.QUERY_EXECUTED_WITH_ERRORS,
                        error: error,
                    });
                    // the above code you can keep it or remove it and manage the error in the
                    // async function
                    // reject with error
                    rej(err);
                } else {
                    // resolve with data
                    res(results);
                }
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            connectorLogger.error(error);

            res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
                message: ErrorMessages.AN_ERROR_OCURRED,
                error: error,
            });
        }).finally(() => {
            connection.end();
        })

    // } catch (error) {
    //     connectorLogger.error(error);

    //     res.status(HttpStatus.StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
    //         message: ErrorMessages.AN_ERROR_OCURRED,
    //         error: error,
    //     });
    // }

    // if you want to keep this code you can have it in a finally statement
    //connection.end();
    // No need it because we are returning above
    // break;
    default:
        throw ErrorMessages.DATABASE_IS_NOT_DEFINED;
}}
```

Comment: I am going to analyze it and test it in this way and I will tell you the result, thanks in advance for the suggestion